# WSLg QtCreator broken menus and no autocompletion

Tags: qt-creator, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I'm using WSlg with Ubuntu 18.04 on windows 11 and I've installed on it the Qt Creator IDE. Via the WSLg I can easily launch it through the start menu of windows 11.

The issue is that while coding with it I have no autocompletion (ctrl + space shows no menu). Also the right click menu after a while goes nuts and start showing in weird places of the screen until it disappears completely; same for the menus on the top bar.

I attach a picture where I show how the right click menu shows up out of the boundaries.

Anyone encountered this issue and has a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So for now I have found a workaround even if it's not a proper solution.

I was using QtCreator installed via the online installer that Qt Provides. I tried using the version that comes with apt-get and I do not have those issues. Also the windowing is different because is showing the usual gray boxing of the WSLg apps; so might be related to the XWayland server architecture or something similar.

Cons of this are that the QtCreator version that comes this way is not up to date with the latest and will rely on the qt libs you have installed on your wsl (being ubuntu 18 will be qt5 and not qt6, meaning you'll not have QtCreator 8).

Also right not I'm having issue on the ClangCodeModel but I think it's a different issue.